# Ionic 5: Menu menu opens on the wrong side RTL

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have a problem with the side menu. It opens from left to right in RTL mode!!
Can anyone help me with that or anyone has fixed this issue

Comment: https://enappd.com/blog/rtl-right-to-left-use-in-ionic-4/50/ 
this may help you.

Comment: @NehaShah I've followed the steps he explained but still facing the same problem